# Erro na hora de compilar: "attribute not allowed"

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Estou tendo problema na hora de compilar um programa no Visual C++ e como sou iniciante, não consigo encontrar onde está o erro.

O programa está rodando perfeitamente no CodeBlocks. Qual pode ser o problema?

Segue o relatório de erro:

[image: relatório do erro]

Comment: Boa tarde Lucas, poste o código, imagens de códigos são mais dificeis de reproduzir, se algo pode ser texto então use texto, realmente é complicado tirar uma foto do código né? Espero que entenda isto como uma critica positiva.

Comment: Você postou só um pequeno trecho do código (e como uma imagem, só para piorar). Fica difícil entender qual é o seu problema sem ter o código todo para analisar.

Comment: Essa foi a primeira postagem minha e eu não tinha noção dessas situações,o problema já foi resolvido graças à resposta do colega abaixo e nas próximas ocasiões estarei atento a essas particularidades.Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está usando o compilador do C++/CLI que é uma linguagem gerenciada que se utiliza do .NET. Esta não é a linguagem C++ que você espera, é outra. Precisa configurar o Visual Studio para usar o C++ padrão.

Você deve ter escolhido um modelo de projeto errado. Veja como deve ser segundo a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/getting-started-with-cpp-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2015&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Por exemplo, foi você que colocou esse `STAThreadAttribute`? Ele está no código que está executando no CodeBlocks? Se não, tire daí.